# Subset a data.frame using a variable for the column name in the select expression

Tags: r, dataframe

Here's the result I want to achieve:

```
> df1 <- data.frame(col1=c(1, 2, 2, 3), col2=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
> subset(df1, col1 == 2)
  col1 col2
2    2    b
3    2    c
```

Except, I want to be able to specify "col1" using a varible:

```
> mycol <- 'col1'
# This just returns the column names and not the rows:
> subset(df1, mycol == 2)
[1] col1 col2
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I want to do this so I can create a function where I can specify the column name to use as a parameter.  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Thank you - I couldn't figure out the right search query to find the answer.  This is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `get()`

```
mycol = 'col1'
subset(df1, get(mycol) == 2)
```

Comment: Thank you - this works and answers the question I asked! However, for anyone else looking at this answer, I believe the duplicate answer links provide a more idiomatic answer (explaining the issues with subset and why bracket notation may be better).